# What does github repository folder with right-arrow mean?

Tags: git, github, directory, icons

I have a github repository folder with a blue icon, that has an right-arrow. I've been unable to find any reference to a github icon legend/key.  Any idea what this icon is?

[image: unknown github icon]

Answer (score 4):

That icon is to indicate a **git submodule**, which has a link to the commit of another git version-controlled project/repository. You can read more about git submodules [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

[image]

The link on the right of the icon points to the commit of another repository which is added in the current repository as a submodule.

The above example is from the [example-dependency](https://github.com/githubtraining/example-dependency) repository.

Answer (score 3):

If, while working on your files locally, you initialized a subdirectory as a git repository (by doing `git init`), when you push these files to GitHub, they just turn into a folder with an arrow to indicate that the folder is a repository within a repository.

If you navigate to that directory and try to view hidden files, you might find a `.git` folder there. If you delete it, the folder will stop becoming a submodule and will show up properly on GitHub.

I have had this happen to me multiple times while creating a react project inside of a git repo.